# Where to find I2C register information for MAX21000+?

Tags: i2c, datasheet

The datasheet for the MAX21000+ IC contains a table listing all of the registers and their default values but doesn't include any description of each of the register bits.

I assume there must be a supporting document but can't find it anywhere. Any ideas?

The datasheet can be found here (warning PDF): http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX21000.pdf

Comment: Just an $0.02.  Consider getting in touch with Maxim.  I too would expect register bit maps in the datasheet, or in a separate user guide.

Comment: Try looking at the 28 mb evaluation kit datasheet. http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/8194

Comment: I can't see anything relevant on that datasheet Passerby - where is the information you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Contact Maxim. We are currently using the chip in a design at my consulting company, and Maxim provided us with a few PDFs that aren't available online. The document you are looking for is named MAX2100x_UG.pdf - it's a 69 page document that goes over the bitfields for every register, as well as some other stuff related to making the chip actually do things. They also gave me some C code examples and a info related to some sort of dev board.